# Can I extract circular buffers from polygon layers?

Tags: raster, r, buffer

I have been working in QGIS with a large and detailed shapefile where remaining forest fragments are represented as polygons. I would like to extract circlular buffers, of various radii, from this vector layer using R. The forest fragment file and a point I need to buffer can be found [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/LD9SO), and a radius I am interested in is 1.128km.

There seem to be [ways to extract circular buffers from rasters](https://rossijeanpierre.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/extracting-circular-buffers-from-a-raster-in-r-12/), but not from polygon layers.  Is the only way for me to perform this operation to first convert my polygon layer into raster form in GRASS, saga-gis, or GDAL?

Comment: You can do that with `dismo::circles` and `raster::intersect`. As you do not provide example data, I cannot show how.

Comment: I have added links to some forest fragments and a point I'd like to buffer above! Thanks for your suggestion, @RobertH. I would love to see how you'd script this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach. Some example data:

```
library(dismo)
# points
n <- 10
set.seed(123)
xy <- cbind(runif(n, -150, 150), runif(n, -50,  50))
# polygons
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0))
p3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0))
p <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3, attr=data.frame(pID = 1:3), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Create circles:

```
cc <- geometry(circles(xy, 1000000, lonlat=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE))
cc <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(cc, data.frame(cid=1:n))
```

Intersect polygons with circles:

```
pc <- intersect(p, cc)
```

Inspect results:

```
plot(p, border='blue', lwd=2)
plot(cc, add=TRUE, border='red', lwd=2)
plot(pc, col='gray', add=TRUE)
```

P.S. with a raster you can do this:

```
r <- raster()
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
buf <- extract(r, xy, buf=100000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The buffer tool from the raster package lets you work with **both** rasters and Spatial* objects. To to create a buffer for a single point:

```
library(raster)
pt <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data.frame(525000,9250000), data = data.frame('Pt1'), proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:32736"))
pt.buf <- buffer(pt, width = 500, )
```

It returns a spatial polygon:

```
> summary(pt.buf)
Object of class SpatialPolygons
Coordinates:
      min     max
x  524500  525500
y 9249500 9250500
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+init=epsg:32736 +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m
+no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
```

Plot it:

```
plot(pt.buf)
points(pt, pch = 19, col = 'red')
```

[image]

For more control over the output, the rgeos package `gbuffer` has more options. To get a buffer with more segments (e.g. 10) and a smoother curve:

```
library(rgeos)
pt.buf2 <- gBuffer(pt, width = 500, quadsegs = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks @Simbamangu ! This seems to have provided a good solution!

Comment: Though this gets one as far as creating the buffer polygons, and not the intersection.  @RobertH has provided me with an example of how to do the intersection (thanks!)

Comment: @Nematode, you should click the √ tick mark next to RobertH's answer to mark it as answered!